# Bootstrap footer Navigation overlaying PopUp Divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013, footer

I am having issues trying to get a Bootstrap 3 footer navigation to underlay correctly on a SharePoint 2013 Intranet site.

This is what I am seeing: http://screencast.com/t/vQFVCBbfE7P

In the Developer Tools, I have attempted to move the z-index down to 0 for the footer navigation itself (which that part works in part, i.e. the grey background is not floating over the popup divs)

My relevant CSS is

```css
 .footerTagline {
     background: #001F5B;
     color: white; 
     padding: 2px 0px;
    }
    
    #bs-footer-nav ul li ul li {
     margin-left: -40px;  
    }
    
    .BHIFooterInfo, .BHIFooterInfo div {
     z-index:0;
     position:inherit !important;
     background: rgb(138,141,143);
    }
    
    .BHIFooterInfo, #companySites {
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    #bs-footer-nav li {
     color:  rgb(241, 180, 52); 
     padding-right: 35px;
    }
    
    #bs-footer-nav li ul li {
     color:  rgb(241, 180, 52); 
     padding-right: 0px;
    }
        
    #bs-footer-nav, #bs-footer-nav a {
     background: rgb(138, 141, 143);
     color: #fff;
    } 
    
    .navbar {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
        
    .footerSocialImages {
     width:23px;
     height: 23px;
    }
    
    #bhiSocialLinks li, #bhiSocialLinks li a {
     padding-left: 0px;
     padding-right: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default BHIFooterInfo">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-footer-nav" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Footer Navigation</a>
           </div>
       
           <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-footer" id="bs-footer-nav">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li>Company Information
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Goals and Initiatives</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">BISSELL Locations</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">BISSELL Strategy</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Corporate Calendar</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Engagement Survey</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Global Business Update</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">MTD Sales</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Organizational Chart</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Press Releases</a></li>
                </ul>
               </li>
               <li>Global BISSELL Sites
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="http://www.bissell.com.au" target="_blank">Australia</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://canada.bissell.com" target="_blank">Canada</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www.bissell.cn" target="_blank">China</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www.bissell.cn" target="_blank">Hong Kong</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www.bissell.nl" target="_blank">Netherlands</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www.bisselldirect.co.uk" target="_blank">United Kingdom</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://www.bissell.com" target="_blank">United States</a></li>
                </ul>
               </li>
               <li>Quick Links
                <ul>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">Associate Take Home Program</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com">BISSELL Outlet Store</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com" target="_blank">Idea Hopper</a></li>
                 <li><a href="linkurl.com" target="_blank">Guest Registration </a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://linkurl.com">Meeting Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://linkurl.com/" target="_blank">Partner Site</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://linkurl.com/" target="_blank">Supplier Site</a></li>
                </ul>
               </li>
             </ul>
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="bhiSocialLinks">
              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bissell" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/Facebook_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/bissellclean/" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/Instagram_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://twitter.com/bissellclean" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/Twitter_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/BISSELLClean" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/YouTube_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="YouTube"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/bissell-homecare-inc-" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/LinkedIn_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="LinkedIn"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.glassdoor.com/Overview/Working-at-BISSELL-EI_IE5594.11,18.htm" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/GlassDoor_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="Glass Door"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/bissellclean/" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/Pinterest_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="Pinterest"></a></li>
              <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+bissell" target="_blank"><img src="/Style Library/Images/socialMedia Links/Google+_white.png" class="footerSocialImages" alt="Google+"></a></li>
             </ul>
           </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
       </nav>
      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Even using !important on the z-index:0 all the way down to the a tag appears to not help.

This issue appears in all browsers.

Things to note on this are:

- The Divs appear to be generated by MS code in JavaScript (for all Div Popup creations)
- It overlays anything in the footer nav that is in the ul or li or a

I realize I am missing something simple, but CSS is not my strong point. Any help is humbly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's the container that the datepicker is featured in that you should be focussing on CSS wise?

Comment: @Lee I had thought about that, but this affects all MS Divs that are popped up (such as search results popups, ellipse menu pop-ups and so forth). So, I was hoping to fix the footer as the root problem, rather than try and reformat all of the Sharepoint div menu/display options

Comment: increase the calendar's z-index and try.

Comment: add calendar code as well

Comment: @dhavalraythatha,  I have tried doing that to both, and neither had worked.

Comment: @RWHertenstein2 how much u did??

Answer (score 0):

add the following code or give me the hosted url to check

```
nav-footer {
  z-index:100 !important;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, and what you're doing differently to correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot now. This is what ended up fixing it:

```
.nav-footer ul li {
    position: inherit;
}
```

While that in and of itself is not helpful, it translates to:

```
.nav-footer ul li {
    position: static;
}
```

when it all cascades out.

**Edit for Clarity**

The containing div had a position:inherit on it. I am uncertain if Bootstrap had a position:relative on their navigation items or not. When i was playing with the z-index again, as indicated in the suggestions, those were not making any difference, even setting them to negative values (with the exception of hiding all the links). When I accidentally clicked off the position:inherit, the links fell under the pop-up divs.

So, I added the same logic to the List Items that was on the footer div. Once I tested it out, it ended up working. I looked at the computed CSS, and it turns out that it inherited the static value (I don't know why it needed to be explicitly stated). Per w3Schools, **static**

> Default value. Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow
>
> > http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

So I am guessing that it just reset everything in the footer to display as it appeared in the code. So, the z-index ended up not being the issue, as I was thinking.